A way to access invocation context in Ballerina Swan Lake
I am working with Ballerina Swan Lake and have a requirement to access the invocation context from another package.
In earlier versions of Ballerina (1.2.x), this was achievable through the runtime library, allowing access to the invocation context and authentication context as described in the documentation.
However, in the newer versions, it appears that the equivalent for the invocation context is http:RequestContext, which I have not found a way to access externally.
Is it possible to access the context of a service invocation directly from the runtime without passing it through a function?

Ballerina Swan Lake does not support the invocation context from runtime. The service specific configuration classes can be used to pass the context information alternatively. This gives more control over the code.
If you need to use the authentication context through the service invocation, please consider using the ballerina/auth module. You can refer to the following.

https://central.ballerina.io/ballerina/auth/2.12.0
https://ballerina.io/spec/auth/


Thanks for the input! So, if we need to pass some properties for each request to other packages, would the way to do it be passing them through the methods called at the service level (like in resource functions)? For example, if we want to pass metadata like the API name, resource name, or some custom data to internal functions, would the idea be to set it in the http:RequestContext and pass it along to those functions?
